# Matlab: Inserting copies of the previous rows, them applying a pattern to 2 columns

Tags: matlab

Another question from the thick guy (me)... apologies - help much appreciated!

Here is an example sample from a larger matrix

```
     0    1.0000    1.0000   60.0000  100.0000         0    0.2500
     0    1.0000    1.0000   62.0000  100.0000    0.2500    0.2500
     0    1.0000    1.0000   63.0000  100.0000    0.5000    0.2500
1.0000    1.0000    1.0000   58.0000  100.0000    0.7500    0.2500
1.0000    1.0000    1.0000   59.0000  100.0000    1.0000    0.2500
1.0000    1.0000    1.0000   65.0000  100.0000    1.2500    0.2500
2.0000    1.0000    1.0000   55.0000  100.0000    1.5000    0.2500
2.0000    1.0000    1.0000   57.0000  100.0000    1.7500    0.2500
2.0000    1.0000    1.0000   60.0000  100.0000    2.0000    0.2500
3.0000    1.0000    1.0000   54.0000  100.0000    2.2500    0.2500
3.0000    1.0000    1.0000   55.0000  100.0000    2.5000    0.2500
3.0000    1.0000    1.0000   59.0000  100.0000    2.7500    0.2500
4.0000    1.0000    1.0000   55.0000  100.0000    3.0000    0.2500
4.0000    1.0000    1.0000   56.0000  100.0000    3.2500    0.2500
4.0000    1.0000    1.0000   60.0000  100.0000    3.5000    0.2500
5.0000    1.0000    1.0000   53.0000  100.0000    3.7500    0.2500
5.0000    1.0000    1.0000   54.0000  100.0000    4.0000    0.2500
5.0000    1.0000    1.0000   59.0000  100.0000    4.2500    0.2500
6.0000    1.0000    1.0000   53.0000  100.0000    4.5000    0.2500
6.0000    1.0000    1.0000   56.0000  100.0000    4.7500    0.2500
6.0000    1.0000    1.0000   58.0000  100.0000    5.0000    0.2500
7.0000    1.0000    1.0000   58.0000  100.0000    5.2500    0.2500
7.0000    1.0000    1.0000   60.0000  100.0000    5.5000    0.2500
7.0000    1.0000    1.0000   65.0000  100.0000    5.7500    0.2500
8.0000    1.0000    1.0000   53.0000  100.0000    6.0000    0.2500
8.0000    1.0000    1.0000   54.0000  100.0000    6.2500    0.2500
8.0000    1.0000    1.0000   63.0000  100.0000    6.5000    0.2500
9.0000    1.0000    1.0000   61.0000  100.0000    6.7500    0.2500
9.0000    1.0000    1.0000   62.0000  100.0000    7.0000    0.2500
9.0000    1.0000    1.0000   65.0000  100.0000    7.2500    0.2500
```

etc....

For every z (the value of z has been prescribed earlier in the code) rows I'd like 3 copies of the rows to be inserted verbatim beneath them as follows (in this example z = 3) :

```
     0    1.0000    1.0000   60.0000  100.0000         0    0.2500
     0    1.0000    1.0000   62.0000  100.0000    0.2500    0.2500
     0    1.0000    1.0000   63.0000  100.0000    0.5000    0.2500
     0    1.0000    1.0000   60.0000  100.0000         0    0.2500
     0    1.0000    1.0000   62.0000  100.0000    0.2500    0.2500
     0    1.0000    1.0000   63.0000  100.0000    0.5000    0.2500
     0    1.0000    1.0000   60.0000  100.0000         0    0.2500
     0    1.0000    1.0000   62.0000  100.0000    0.2500    0.2500
     0    1.0000    1.0000   63.0000  100.0000    0.5000    0.2500
     0    1.0000    1.0000   60.0000  100.0000         0    0.2500
     0    1.0000    1.0000   62.0000  100.0000    0.2500    0.2500
     0    1.0000    1.0000   63.0000  100.0000    0.5000    0.2500
1.0000    1.0000    1.0000   58.0000  100.0000    0.7500    0.2500
1.0000    1.0000    1.0000   59.0000  100.0000    1.0000    0.2500
1.0000    1.0000    1.0000   65.0000  100.0000    1.2500    0.2500
1.0000    1.0000    1.0000   58.0000  100.0000    0.7500    0.2500
1.0000    1.0000    1.0000   59.0000  100.0000    1.0000    0.2500
1.0000    1.0000    1.0000   65.0000  100.0000    1.2500    0.2500
1.0000    1.0000    1.0000   58.0000  100.0000    0.7500    0.2500
1.0000    1.0000    1.0000   59.0000  100.0000    1.0000    0.2500
1.0000    1.0000    1.0000   65.0000  100.0000    1.2500    0.2500
1.0000    1.0000    1.0000   58.0000  100.0000    0.7500    0.2500
1.0000    1.0000    1.0000   59.0000  100.0000    1.0000    0.2500
1.0000    1.0000    1.0000   65.0000  100.0000    1.2500    0.2500
```

etc

Next I'd like column 1 to be replaced and to now have the pattern

```
[0 0 0 5 5 5 10 11 12 17 17 17 ]
```

which would then repeat (always from 5 integers later, until the end of the pattern so that the next 12 entries would be:

```
[22 22 22 27 27 27 32 33 34 39 39 39]
```

and so on.

It would be great if the code were relatively idiot-friendly (me-friendly) so 
that I can easily manipulate this repeating pattern if need be. For example if z 
were 4 rather than 3 then I would want the pattern

```
[0 0 0 0 5 5 5 5 10 11 12 13 18 18 18 18]
```

...Column 6 should then be replaced with a column that relates to column
1 in a (column_1 * 0.25) relationship. 
i.e. for the above sample, where column 1 is:

```
[0 0 0 5 5 5 10 11 12 17 17 17 22 22 22 27 27 27 32 33 34 39 39 39]
```

column 6 would be:

```
[0 0 0 1.2500 1.2500 1.2500 2.5000 2.7500 3.0000 4.2500 4.2500 4.2500 5.5000
5.5000 5.5000 6.7500 6.7500 6.7500 8.0000 8.2500 8.5000 9.7500 9.7500       
9.7500]
```

Can you help with that at all? Thanks very much in advance

Comment: Short idea about the second part: `[0 0 0 5 5 5 10 11 12 17 17 17 ]`  --> `A = [zeros(1,N) 5*ones(1,N) 10:(9+N) 17*ones(1,N)]`, then replicate this vector i times, and always add +22. E.g. like this: `B = repmat(A', 1, m)` and then add the value k*22 to each column, whereas k is the column-index (starting at 0). `m` is the length of your final matrix divided by N (in your example 3). Then `B(:)` will be your first column of your final matrix. And `B(:)*0.25` will be the sixth column.

Comment: @tim Thanks for that! All makes sense to me except for the column index bit. I understand the idea that each column could be indexed with numbers from 0 upwards and then adding a value of k*22 would then add 22* whatever the column index is... but how do I set it up so that k is the index in the first place (sorry for the undoubtedly stupid question...) thanks!

Comment: What I meant is: You have 6 columns, so you'd give a row-vector `k=0:5` (0 representing the first column). Now multiply this by 22 --> `k=(0:5)*22=[0 22 44 66 88]`, as a row-vector. Now you could sum this row vector to every row of `B`, i.e. in the first column, to every entry you'll add 0. In the second column (k=1) you'll so add 22 and so on... Now you'd have a matrix `B2` which consists of: column 0 == A, column 1 == A+22, column 2 = A+44 and so on.

Comment: And if you linearize a matrix as `B2(:)` this will yield a vector containing all values of the first column of B2, then the second column of B2 and so on... this is, because MATLAB is column major, see this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order

Comment: I provided my full solution as well, the first part being done by simple matrix-indexing, I hope you can follow my comments in my solution

Comment: Thanks a lot for all of this - I'm out and about now, but I'll give it a look later - much appreciated!

Comment: Had a look already? If yes, consider accepting an answer and upvoting at least as it took quite some efforts and this is how SO works..

Comment: Thanks Tim - sorry I'm being a little slow but don't worry, I am (and have been) planning on it. Thanks again for your help - very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also want to provide a second solution, everything you need to know is provided as comments:

```
%%% INPUT DATA %%%
N = 3;
[~, A]=meshgrid(1:7,1:21);
numRows = size(A, 1);

if(mod(numRows, N) ~= 0)
    % do padding here so that numRows can be devided by N, you can do it yourself :-)
end

%%% FIRST PART %%%
cnt = reshape(1:numRows,[N, numRows/N])     % create matrix which contains indices 1:numRows (number of Rows of A) in the desired manner
idx = repmat(cnt, N+1, 1)                       % number of copies of every line you want: N (so you'd have N+1 entries of every row (1 base and N copies))
A_cop = A(idx(:), :)                        % now idx(:) will give you the row-indices to replicate the rows of A in the desired manner
% --> 3-liner :-) could even be summed up in one single codeline :D

%%% SECOND PART %%%
c = [zeros(1,N) 5*ones(1,N) 10:(9+N) 17*ones(1,N)];     % base format
c2 = repmat(c', 1, ceil(size(A_cop, 1)/length(c)));     % replicate it so that +i*22 can be added easily column-wise (i=column index)
c3 = bsxfun(@plus, c2, [(0:(size(c2,2)-1))]*22);
firstCol = c3(:);                                       % linearize column-major memory

%%% THIRD PART -> merge both parts %%%
A_cop(:, 1) = firstCol(1:size(A_cop,1));        % set first column
A_cop(:, 6) = A_cop(:, 1)*0.25;
```

I think my first part might be a bit easier to understand then the solution from Bill, isnt it?

Im using indexing to copy rows within the input matrix `A`. That means, I generate a vector which contains the row-indices which I want to take from A, and this vector can contain values multiple times.

My example index-vector looks like this:

```
>> idx(:)
ans =

1
2
3
1
2
3
1
2
3
1
2
3
4
5
6
4
5
6
4
5
6
4
5
6
7
8
9
    ...
```

Using this, I make the final matrix `A_cop` and afterwards I apply the second part as described above in the comment --> replicate the base format `c` in a matrix and sum +i*22 in the i-th column, then linearizing the memory to yield one row-vector :-)

Answer (score 2):

### **TL;DR : For the final code : Go to section Full Code**

The first part at least looks like a good job for [reshape](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) and [repmat](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repmat.html).
The tricky part is to not mess up with the dimensions.
Another approach will be to use cells and the function [cellfun](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html).

In this answer i will use a toy example defined as follow :

```
[~,ArrayIn]=meshgrid(1:7,1:20);

ArrayIn =

    1    1    1    1    1    1    1
    2    2    2    2    2    2    2
    3    3    3    3    3    3    3
                 .....

z=3;
```

### **1. FIRST APPROACH : Use `repmat` and `reshape` :**

Now, basically, the code will operate 3 major steps :

**Step 1 : reshape the matrix so that it becomes a matrix of size `size(ArrayIn,2)xzxsize(ArrayIn,1)/z`**

```
reshapedArrayIn=reshape(ArrayIn.',size(ArrayIn,2),z,[]);
```

Note that, after this step, the slices along the 3rd dimension are exactly the slices of length `z` that you want to repeat 3 times (only they are transposed, but it's needed because of the way reshape works).

```
reshapedArrayIn =

ans(:,:,1) =

   1   2   3
   1   2   3
   1   2   3
   1   2   3
   1   2   3
   1   2   3
   1   2   3

ans(:,:,2) =

   4   5   6
   4   5   6
   4   5   6
   4   5   6
   4   5   6
   4   5   6
   4   5   6
      ...
```

Also note that if the number of rows in your matrix is not dividable by `z` in the first place, the code will fail and you'll have to add extra lines before the call to `reshape` in order for it to work :

```
% Optional
if mod(size(ArrayIn,1),z)~=0

    ArrayIn=[ArrayIn;zeros(z-mod(size(ArrayIn,1),z),size(ArrayIn,2))];

end
```

**Step 2 : repeat the matrix 3 times along the second dimension**

```
repArray=repmat(reshapedArrayIn,1,3,1);
```

**Step 3 : reshape your matrix again in order to get a 2 dimensional matrix back, transpose the result to get it right**

```
ArrayOut=reshape(repArray,size(ArrayIn,2),size(ArrayIn,1)*3).';
```

**The result is as intended :**

```
ArrayOut =

    1    1    1    1    1    1    1
    2    2    2    2    2    2    2
    3    3    3    3    3    3    3
    1    1    1    1    1    1    1
    2    2    2    2    2    2    2
    3    3    3    3    3    3    3
                  ...
```

### **2. SECOND APPROACH : use `cellfun`**

Another possibility to achieve this would be to convert you matrix to a cell and then use the function [cellfun](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html) on all your subcells (This code would go after `ArrayIn` has been padded so that its number of rows is dividable by `z`:

```
Idy=7;
Idx=z*ones(size(ArrayIn,1)/z,1);

ArrayCell=mat2cell(ArrayIn,Idx,Idy);

CellOut=cellfun(@(A) repmat(A,3,1),ArrayCell,'UniformOutput',false);

ArrayOut=cell2mat(CellOut);
```

Giving also the expected result :

```
ArrayOut =

    1    1    1    1    1    1    1
    2    2    2    2    2    2    2
    3    3    3    3    3    3    3
    1    1    1    1    1    1    1
    2    2    2    2    2    2    2
    3    3    3    3    3    3    3
                  ...
```

### **PART 2**

For this part you can use what @tim gave you in the comments, although with a slight modification to take the length of your columns into account :

```
A = [zeros(1,z) 5*ones(1,z) 10:(9+z) 17*ones(1,z)];

m=ceil(size(ArrayOut,1)/(4*z));

UncutCol=repmat(A.',1,m)+repmat(22(*0:(m-1)),length(A),1);

Column1Out=UncutCol(1:size(ArrayOut,1));

Column6Out=Column1Out*0.25;

ArrayOut(:,1)=Column1Out;

ArrayOut(:,6)=Column6Out;
```

### **FULL CODE :**

**Approach 1 :**

```
z=3;

[~,ArrayIn]=meshgrid(1:7,1:20);

if mod(size(ArrayIn,1),z)~=0

    ArrayIn=[ArrayIn;zeros(z-mod(size(ArrayIn,1),z),size(ArrayIn,2))];

end

reshapedArrayIn=reshape(ArrayIn.',size(ArrayIn,2),z,[]);

repArray=repmat(reshapedArrayIn,1,3,1);

ArrayOut=reshape(repArray,size(ArrayIn,2),size(ArrayIn,1)*3).';

A = [zeros(1,z) 5*ones(1,z) 10:(9+z) 17*ones(1,z)];

m=ceil(size(ArrayOut,1)/(4*z));

UncutCol=repmat(A.',1,m)+repmat(22*(0:(m-1)),length(A),1);

Column1Out=UncutCol(1:size(ArrayOut,1));

Column6Out=Column1Out*0.25;

ArrayOut(:,1)=Column1Out;

ArrayOut(:,6)=Column6Out;
```

**Approach 2 :**

```
z=3;

[~,ArrayIn]=meshgrid(1:7,1:20);

if mod(size(ArrayIn,1),z)~=0

    ArrayIn=[ArrayIn;zeros(z-mod(size(ArrayIn,1),z),size(ArrayIn,2))];

end

Idy=7;
Idx=z*ones(size(ArrayIn,1)/z,1);

ArrayCell=mat2cell(ArrayIn,Idx,Idy);

CellOut=cellfun(@(A) repmat(A,3,1),ArrayCell,'UniformOutput',false);

ArrayOut=cell2mat(CellOut);

A = [zeros(1,z) 5*ones(1,z) 10:(9+z) 17*ones(1,z)];

m=ceil(size(ArrayOut,1)/(4*z));

UncutCol=repmat(A.',1,m)+repmat(22*(0:(m-1)),length(A),1);

Column1Out=UncutCol(1:size(ArrayOut,1));

Column6Out=Column1Out*0.25;

ArrayOut(:,1)=Column1Out;

ArrayOut(:,6)=Column6Out;
```

### Final Result :

> ```
> ArrayOut =
>
>          0    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000         0    1.0000
>          0    2.0000    2.0000    2.0000    2.0000         0    2.0000
>          0    3.0000    3.0000    3.0000    3.0000         0    3.0000
>     5.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.2500    1.0000
>     5.0000    2.0000    2.0000    2.0000    2.0000    1.2500    2.0000
>     5.0000    3.0000    3.0000    3.0000    3.0000    1.2500    3.0000
>    10.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    2.5000    1.0000
>    11.0000    2.0000    2.0000    2.0000    2.0000    2.7500    2.0000
>    12.0000    3.0000    3.0000    3.0000    3.0000    3.0000    3.0000
>    17.0000    4.0000    4.0000    4.0000    4.0000    4.2500    4.0000
>    17.0000    5.0000    5.0000    5.0000    5.0000    4.2500    5.0000
>    17.0000    6.0000    6.0000    6.0000    6.0000    4.2500    6.0000
>    22.0000    4.0000    4.0000    4.0000    4.0000    5.5000    4.0000
>    22.0000    5.0000    5.0000    5.0000    5.0000    5.5000    5.0000
>    22.0000    6.0000    6.0000    6.0000    6.0000    5.5000    6.0000
>                                 .....
> ```